# How to change keyup change to onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(":input").bind("keyup change", function(e) {
    var comboVal = $('.emailrequerido1').val()+$('.emailrequerido2').val()+$('.emailrequerido3').val()+$('.emailrequerido4').val()+$('.emailrequerido5').val();
        if(comboVal == 'nullnull' || comboVal == ""){
            $("#enviarForm").attr('disabled', true);
        }else{
            $("#enviarForm").removeAttr('disabled');
        }
});
```

I want it to work that whenever their is a change in the field the button should enable **without having to click out of the box**

If the field has memorized a value and you double click the field and select the value the button stays disabled until you click out of the field.

Comment: delete the change event, but you should use a timeout function, which delayes the keyup event. (Performance)

Comment: @pc-shooter could you put an example with my code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate a memorized value in an input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636052/how-to-validate-a-memorized-value-in-an-input-field)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Timeout function inside event bind function

```
$(":input").on("keyup", function(e) {
   setTimeout(function () {

    // gets the text in the field after a specified time (100 milliseconds)
    var comboVal = $('.emailrequerido1').val()+$('.emailrequerido2').val()+$('.emailrequerido3').val()+$('.emailrequerido4').val()+$('.emailrequerido5').val();
    if(comboVal == 'nullnull' || comboVal == ""){
        $("#enviarForm").attr('disabled', true);
    }else{
        $("#enviarForm").removeAttr('disabled');
    }

   }, 100);
});
```

Comment: That still doesnt work when I double click the field and click on a memorized value in that field. When I do this the button stays disabled and this is what I want to fix.

Comment: Try the modified function

Comment: use keypress event instead of keyup

Comment: @MONZTAAA "_The `keyup` event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on the keyboard_", if you want to specially catch double click use `dblclick`